# How can I model this schema in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I asked this in the DevOps forum, but this is probably a better one for this question.

I want to create a schema that reflects the following relationships, and I'm trying to do this in MySQL Workbench. (I'm no DB expert)

- I have 3 environments - sandbox, staging, and production
- I release a product version in each environment, e.g., `sb-1.0.0` for sandbox, `st-1.0.0` for staging, and `pr-1.0.0` for production. I can have multiple releases per environment, but there can only be ONE version that's currently released in each environment.
- Each product version in each environment contains a set of services, same set of services in all the environments, but differing in their version numbers. So `sb-1.0.0 = [svc1-2.0.0, svc2-2.0.0], st-1.0.0 = [svc1-1.0.0, svc2-2.0.0], and pr-1.0.0 = [svc1-1.0.0, svc2-1.0.0]`. As you can see, I have the same 2 services in all environments, but the service versions can be different (or the same) in each  environment.

I want to accomplish multiple things.

- I want to be able to create new releases in each environment, with each release containing the set of services and corresponding versions. So I want to be able to create a `pr-2.0.0 = [svc1-2.0.0, svc2-1.0.0]` version.
- I want to be able to query my DB for version `pr-1.0.0` and know all the services and their respective versions in this particular release.
- I want to have the notion of a "current version" and a "desired version" for each service in each environment.
- I want to be be able to then run a script (Kubernetes?) to release each service and their respective version based on the query.
- I want to be able to extend it to more environments, e.g., add a UAT environment.

So how do I model my DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've thought through what you want things to be/do.  So the next step is to define the necessary entities, the relationships/cardinalities between them, and the proper keys.

So just looking over things, it looks like we have `Environment`, `Service`. `ServiceVersion`, `Product`, `ProductVersion`, `ProductVersionEnvironment` (to relate `ProductVersion` to `Environment`), `ProductVersionService` (to relate a `ServiceVersion` to a `ProductVersion`), and possibly a few helpers to enforce valid value selections.

So we need to organize this in some sort of hierarchy.  Let's start with:
[image]

Now we need to determine the relationships between each connected entity and the cardinality:

`Product has 1 to many ProductVersions`

`Environment hosts zero to many ProductVersions`

`Service has 1 to many ServiceVersions`

`ProductVersion uses 0 to many ServiceVersions`

Done.  Now to understand the keys (beginning at the top of the hierarchy and working down):

For `Environment`, the `Name` is the natural key, but it looks like you already have shorthand values picked out.  Let's call those `EnvironmentCd` and make that the primary key (we will have an alternate key on `Name` to ensure uniqueness).

For `Service`, again the `Name` is what guarantees uniqueness, but shorthand codes work well for the sake of brevity (storage really isn't a concern at this point).  So we'll make the primary key `ServiceCd` and demote `Name` to an alternate key.

For `ServiceVersion`, the key is `(ServiceCd, VersionNbr)`.

We'll do something similar for `Product` and `ProductVersion`: `ProductCd` and `(ProductCd, VersionNbr)` respectively.

Now for `ProductVersionService`, the key becomes `(ProductVersion, VersionNbr, ServiceCd)` as I don't think you would have different versions of the same services used within a release.

The key for `ProductVersionEnvironment` is `(ProductCd, VersionNbr, EnvironmentCd)`.

Sticking everything together:

```
CREATE TABLE Environment
(
  EnvironmentCd  CHAR(2)      NOT NULL
 ,Name           VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Environment PRIMARY KEY (EnvironmentCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_Environment UNIQUE (Name)
)
;

CREATE TABLE Product
(
  ProductCd  CHAR(4)      NOT NULL
 ,Name       VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Product PRIMARY KEY (ProductCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_Product UNIQUE (Name)
)
;

CREATE TABLE ProductVersion
(
  ProductCd   CHAR(4)      NOT NULL
 ,VersionNbr  VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL
 ,VersionDt   DATE         NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ProductVersion_Version_Of_Product FOREIGN KEY (ProductCd) REFERENCES Product (ProductCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_ProductVersion PRIMARY KEY (ProductCd, VersionNbr)
)
;

CREATE TABLE Service
(
  ServiceCd  CHAR(4)      NOT NULL
 ,Name       VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Service PRIMARY KEY (ServiceCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_Service UNIQUE (Name)
)
;

CREATE TABLE ServiceVersion
(
  ServiceCd    CHAR(4)      NOT NULL
 ,VersionNbr   VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL
 ,VersionDt    DATE         NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ServiceVersion_Version_Of_Service FOREIGN KEY (ServiceCd) REFERENCES Service (ServiceCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_ServiceVersion PRIMARY KEY (ServiceCd, VersionNbr)
)
;

CREATE TABLE ProductVersionEnvironment
(
  ProductCd      CHAR(4)      NOT NULL
 ,VersionNbr     VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL
 ,EnvironmentCd  CHAR(2)      NOT NULL
 ,DeployedAt     DATETIME(3)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_Environment_Hosts_ProductVersion FOREIGN KEY (ProductCd, VersionNbr) REFERENCES ProductVersion (ProductCd, VersionNbr)
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ProductVersion_Deployed_To_Environment FOREIGN KEY (EnvironmentCd) REFERENCES Environment (EnvironmentCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_ProductVersionEnvironment PRIMARY KEY (ProductCd, VersionNbr, EnvironmentCd)
)
;

CREATE TABLE ProductVersionService
(
  ProductCd          CHAR(4)      NOT NULL
 ,VersionNbr         VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL
 ,ServiceCd          CHAR(4)      NOT NULL
 ,ServiceVersionNbr  VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ServiceVersion_Used_In_ProductVersion FOREIGN KEY (ProductCd, VersionNbr) REFERENCES ProductVersion (ProductCd, VersionNbr)
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ProductVersion_Uses_ServiceVersion FOREIGN KEY (ServiceCd, ServiceVersionNbr) REFERENCES ServiceVersion (ServiceCd, VersionNbr)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_ProductVersionService PRIMARY KEY (ProductCd, VersionNbr, ServiceCd)
)
;
```

Now to denote the current version/release in each environment, we can either:

1. Set a flag in `ProductVersionEnvironment`
2. Use when the `ProductVersion` was deployed in the `Environment` and denote the most recent record the current version
3. Create a table with the primary key `(ProductCd, EnvironmentCd)`

The first option requires we write a bunch of code to ensure only one `ProductVersion` is selected as the current version, and the possibility exists if that code fails/is circumvented there will be an error.

The second option assumes you won't deploy older versions at later dates/testing, so that's one.

Third option would only require the insertion/update/deletion of a single row per `Product` and `Environment`, cannot be circumvented, and is foolproof.  We implement it like so:

```
CREATE TABLE EnvironmentCurrentProductVersion
(
  EnvironmentCd  CHAR(2)      NOT NULL
 ,ProductCd      CHAR(4)      NOT NULL
 ,VersionNbr     VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_EnvironmentCurrentProductVersion_Is_ProductVersionEnvironment (ProductCd, VersionNbr, EnvironmentCd) REFERENCES ProductVersionEnvironment (ProductCd, VersionNbr, EnvironmentCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_EnvironmentCurrentProductVersion PRIMARY KEY (EnvironmentCd, ProductCd)
)
;
```

In ER Diagram form:
[image]

This should be enough to get you started - any additional attributes you need should be easy to assign to the correct entity.

Comment: Thank you! The `CREATE TABLE ProductVersionService` query errored since `ProductVersionNbr` column is not defined. Which should be changed, the primary key definition, or the column?

Comment: @ChrisF - I typed everything freehand, let me update the answer

Comment: @bbarid, since I can't post pics on a comment, I posted an answer that contains the ER diagram as a result of executing your queries. It has some mismatching relationships compared to your ER diagram.

Comment: That's an oops on my part again - I had the wrong FK reference for  `EnvironmentCurrentProductVersion`

Comment: @ChrisF when in doubt follow the pretty picture and not my code :)

Comment: all good now. I wanted to follow your code to understand the structure better. (I'm a linux/CLI kinda guy). Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119016/discussion-between-chris-f-and-bbaird).